# обращение к ассоциативному массиву

Tags: php

Предположим что есть переменная:

```
$test = 'test1.test2.test3';
```

И есть массив, где есть такой элемент:

```
$array['test1']['test2']['test3] = 'value';
```

Есть ли лайфхак как обратится по значению к элементам массива?

**ГРУБО** говоря я хочу типа такого:

```
$get_value = $array[*$test*];
```

Еще раз подчеркну, что это **грубо**, просто понятен сам смысл того, что мне надо.

Comment: @XYZ Да, нашел что искал.

Comment: добавил туда еще ответ и ссылку на аналогичный случай https://stackoverflow.com/a/27930028/6104996